# Change filename of uploaded file and store it in database

Tags: php, database, file

I'm trying to figure out a way to get uploaded file, change its name to random string of characters + its extension and save it (as a path) in a database.

I'm stuck at this stage (can get a file / filename and generate random string).

```
    $image = $_FILES["image"]["name"];

    //Random string generator
    function randomString($length = 15) {
        $characters = "0ab";
        $randomString = "";
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }
```

and essentially get something like `$imagePath = "img/" . $newFilename;` where `$newFilename` is random string + extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
//Random string generator
function randomString($length = 15) {
    $characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $randomString = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$filename = randomString().'.'.pathinfo($_FILES["image"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
```